# PHP - How to change specific word in string using array

Tags: php

```
$str = "Hello {{name}} welcome to {{company_name}}";

$array = ['name' => 'max', 'company_name' => 'Stack Exchange'];
```

how to replace {{name}} and {{company_name}} using array value. any php function that return output like

```
Hello max welcome to Stack Exchange
```

Comment: it's work for preg_replace_callback

Comment: thanks for your reply can you give me example

Comment: If your goal was printing rather than getting a string, try `echo 'Hello'.$name.', Welcome to '.$company;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a new array with your search fields, wrapped in curly braces:

```
$searchArray = array_map(function($value) {
    return "{{" . $value . "}}";
}, array_keys($array));
```

Now you have an array with the tokens you are searching for, and you already have an array of values you want to replace the tokens with.

So just do a simple `str_replace`:

```
echo str_replace($searchArray, $array, $str);
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/8tPZt

---

Here's a tidy little function put together:

```
function fillTemplate($templateString, array $searchReplaceArray) {
    return str_replace(
        array_map(function($value) { return "{{" . $value . "}}"; }, array_keys($searchReplaceArray)),
        $searchReplaceArray,
        $templateString
    );
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
echo fillTemplate(
    "Hello {{name}} welcome to {{company_name}}",
    ['name' => 'max', 'company_name' => 'Stack Exchange']
);

// Hello max welcome to Stack Exchange
```

Example: https://3v4l.org/rh0KX

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this nice function of PHP: http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtr.php
You can find there examples and explanation of it.

```
$str = "Hello {{name}} welcome to {{company_name}}";

$array = ['{{name}}' => 'max', '{{company_name}}' => 'Stack Exchange'];

print strtr ($str, $array);
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: OK, then...i change it

Comment: Nice edit, but you don't explain it.

Comment: English is not my bith language, but i still try to help. And i personally would prefer Link. If that against the concept of Stack Overflow. Sry. For me is SO instant help on instant qeustions. I agree some explanations should way more detailed, but not on this question here ;)

Comment: @Jay Blanchard and when i see your reputaion, why arent you answering instead of copy&paste your comment ??

Comment: Because I am not going to add yet another answer to a duplicate question. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ I have dozens of copy 'n paste comments because so many do the same exact thing over and over again.

Comment: Still funny to help here, always funny. Hopefully someday we can generate an StackOverflowWiki from all that good answers ;)

Comment: In this case I was trying to help you to improve your answer. Just trying to help all the way around.

Comment: But you didn't vote up in the first place ;) But thanks for helping me helping. opps - avoid extended discussions , Have a nice day